# Как сделать сортировку по количеству записей MySql

Tags: mysql

Вот запрос, но он почему-то возвращает одну только запись а не все отсортированые

```
SELECT
  COUNT(r.id) AS co,
  profile.name
FROM profile
JOIN reviews r
  ON r.id_user_work_task = profile.id_user
ORDER BY co
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно уловил суть вопроса, то можно добавить директиву *group by*. прмерно так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as co, profile.name
FROM profile
JOIN reviews r ON r.id_user_work_task = profile.id_user
group by profile.name
ORDER BY co
```